# Vue Bootstrap fluid container wrong breakpoints

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I need a container, such that it would take 100% aavilable width until breakpoint (max-width). After reading [official docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout#responsive-fluid-containers), responsive fluid container seemed like a perfect choice.

> Responsive containers are new in Bootstrap v4.4. They allow you to specify a container that is 100% wide (fluid) until particular breakpoint is reached at which point a max-width is applied.

[Breakpoints table from official docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX0gF.png)
which says that *md* breakpoint is maxed to 720px. But that behaviour is different in reality.
During testing I discovered, that container-md max-width is set to 960px if viewport is more that 992px.

[screenshot of active css rule on container-md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8T3I.png)

`<b-container fluid="md">`[reproduced Codepen](https://codepen.io/ironcondor/pen/OJyVvyp)

Do I not understand docs correctly? Is there components with above described functionality?

Comment: containers have a padding of 15px on the left and right.  You can remove this padding with class `px-0` or remove it only on md screend and up with class `px-md-0`

Comment: @TroyMorehouse that does not change the behaviour described in the post

Comment: Here is hte link to the official Bootstrap v4.4.1 docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive

BootstrapVue uses Bootstrap V4.4.1 SCSS (which would normally be default breakpoints, unless you have customized SCSS/CSS)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_grid.scss

Comment: @TroyMorehouse Once again, I don't see how it answers my question. The only thing that comes to my mind is that boostrap `container-{}` and vue-boostrap `fluid={}` behave the same way (which is also justified by inspecting css rules, see screenshot in initial post), but vue-boostrap docs wording is misleading. In contrast, bootstrap not only explicitly say "For example, .container-sm is 100% wide to start until the sm breakpoint is reached, **where it will scale up with md, lg, and xl.**". But also provides a table, where such behaviour is represented, unlike vue-bootstrap table.

Comment: See https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout#grid-options

Note I have posted comments and not answers. If I were fully answering I would have posted an answer below. ;)

Comment: I have since added,  as an answer, a link to the docs section that outlines the container maximum widths for the various breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The container max-widths for the various breakpoints (assuming default SCSS vars) are listed in the layout docs at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout#grid-options

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` added in your custom.scss
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#using-custom-bootstrap-scss

This work for me.

```
 <b-container :fluid="'md'">
</b-container>
```

in inspect element it should be class="container-md"

[image]